# Ionic's PWA Styles are not applied on iOS devices

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

**My Progressive Web App** I made with `Ionic and Angular 8` looks nice on Chrome and `Android devices`.
But if I switch to an `iOS device`, the Styles are not applied correctly.

`Buttons, Icons and the Titlebar-Font` has wrong colors.

To make my App run i use `ng build --prod` and copy the generated www folder to my Webserver.

**edit**
found the error. The iPad was not updated. The iOS version was outdated.

Answer (score 1):

check related links [ios ui is different then android and browser ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196614/ios-ui-is-different-then-android-and-browser-ionic/57196759#57196759)

Comment: Changing it to "md" made my until then hidden Burger-Menu-Button visible, but nothing else changed.   sorry for deleting my comment, i had another problem and thought i should fix it before i answer.

Comment: The solution was, that the testdevices got no updates since a long period. After the iOS update everything worked fine.